# Do I only discard down to 10 after drawing 2 cards on my turn?

Tags: smash-up

If at any time outside of my turn I end up with more than 10 cards, for instance from having cards returned to my hand by another's action, do I keep and play from them on my turn only to discard down to 10 cards after I draw two cards on my turn?

The only mention of discarding down to 10 is on page 4 where it explains drawing two cards: "If you have more than 10 after drawing, discard down to 10."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes.

Your hand limit only applies after your draw step.

From [the most recent rulebook](http://www.alderac.com/smashup/files/2014/11/SU7_Rulebook.pdf), "This Is How You Roll" turn order on *page 5*:

> ### 4. Draw 2 Cards
>
> Just what it says: draw 2 cards. If you need to draw, reveal, search for or look at a card and your deck is empty, shuffle your discard pile. Put it on the table face down — that’s your new deck. Start drawing from there.
>
> The maximum number of cards you can have in your hand **at this time** is 10. If you have more than 10 **after drawing**, discard down to 10.